# How do I redirect a page into an error page

Tags: python, html, redirect

So this is my code, and I want it to redirect the page, if a user types nothing in to it, then press "add". I need some help
        {% extends "base.html" %}

```
    {% block content %}

    <form>
        <h2>Add a Food</h2>
        <input type="text" name="food">
        {% if items %}
            {% for item in items %}
              <input type="hidden" name="food" value="{{item}}">
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        <button>Add</button>

            <br>
            <br>

            <h2>Shopping List</h2>
            <ul>
                {% if items %}
                    {% for item in items %}

                {% for item in items %}
                    <li>{{ item }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
                    <h3>comments</h3>
                    {% for comement in item %}
                        <li>{{ comment }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
            </ul>
    </form>

    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why you want to redirect it to an error page instead of alerting the user to enter something?

Comment: Ahhh that's pretty good idea! Thanks, but I do want to learn how to do this tho

Comment: just set an id to button tag and add a script like `$('#button').click(function(){ ... })`

Comment: Thank you I think that helped, along with the kind answer from the gentleman below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect would not actually go in the HTML page for the form (if you are emitting HTML, it is already too late), but rather in the HTTP handler for the target of the form. That is, if your form looks like:

```
 <form action="/form/submission" method="post">
```

... the handler for "/form/submission" would do this redirect. That is, it would emit:

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other 
Location: http://your.server.com/path/to/error
```

Instead of:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
... (content here) ...
```

How you do this in the handler will depend on the particular server environment and framework. For webapp2 and Google App Engine, it would look something like this:

```
class PostHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

   def post(self):
      if missing_inputs(self.request):
         self.response.redirect_to(new_location)
      process_form_submission(self.request)
```

However, to provide more specific help, we'd need to know the server-side technology.

It is also possible to do a "redirect" on the client, by including JavaScript that assigns to the variable `window.location.href`; however, if you have validation in JavaScript, it would make a lot more sense to annotate the error on the current page (e.g. display/reveal an error message above the form), rather than taking the user to a completely different page if you are doing this in JavaScript.